# FILENAME WHEN USING DiffDrivePlugin6w hector_gazebo plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can someone tell me which filename do I have to put here: (if I write   libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so  it doesn't work...)

[image: image description]

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9182/filename-when-using-diffdriveplugin6w-hector_gazebo-plugin/) by [ROS_GAZEBO_USER](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1326/ros_gazebo_user/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The filename is libdiffdrive_plugin_6w.so  (you can see it when you do the catkin_make)

---

Originally posted by [ROS_GAZEBO_USER](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1326/ros_gazebo_user/) with karma: 15 on 2015-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0